# In Romans 3:30 why are the circumcised justified "by [εκ] faith" but the gentiles "through [δια] faith"?

Tags: romans, justification

Romans 3:30 says that

> Seeing it is one God, which shall justify the circumcision **by faith**, and uncircumcision **through faith**. (KJV)

Since the just shall live by faith, I don't understand why the text seems to make a distinction in how justification is done for the Jew and the Gentile, for the first group of people God shall justify BY faith ('εκ' in Greek) and the latter group justification is done THROUGH faith ('δια' in Greek).

Is there a reason for the Greek language to use two different prepositions here?

Comment: The difference in the English prepositions is a direct translation and reflection of the underlying Greek Propositions.

Comment: I understand this, Mac, I should have phrased my question differently, asking: why does the Greek use two different propositions.

Comment: Sorry to ask @Mac'sMusings but did you mean 'underlying Greek _Prepositions_' or were you specifically referring to underlying concepts, not the words on the page ?

Comment: Yes - my typo - apologies.

Answer (score 6):

The prepositions used by Paul in the question are the same, in relation to justification, as he uses in Philippians 3:9 :

> And be found in him, not having mine own righteousness, which is of the law, but that which is **through** the faith of Christ, the righteousness which is of God **by** faith: Phiippians 3:9 [KJV]

Here, Paul emphasises that justification is a matter of the righteousness of God. The righteousness wherewith men are justified is God's own righteousness.

And as he says previously in Romans :

> For therein [in the gospel] is the righteousness of God revealed from faith to faith Romans 1:17 [KJV]

By the revelation of God's own righteousness (demonstrated in the sufferings and death of Jesus Christ, his own Son) and **by** faith in that demonstration, men are justified.

But it is also **through** the faith of Christ himself in offering up himself.

*The agency is **through** the faith of Christ.*

*The means is **by** the faith of the believer.*

Thus in Romans 3:30 Paul emphasises that the believing Jews are justified **by** their own faith, not their previous works, these works being immaterial to justification. Paul emphasises the **means** of believing, as opposed to the useless works of the flesh.

Whereas Paul emphasises to Gentiles that justification is **through** faith (that is to say the faith of Christ) and thus draws attention to the grace of Christ in reaching even to the far off Gentiles who had no means at all at their disposal to draw near to God. Thus Paul emphasises the **agency** of Christ to the far off gentiles.